# Maximum of the minimal distance of a set of points in an equilateral triangle

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, optimization

In this question, a closed triangle on a plane is a set of all points in its area and on its boundary, while an open triangle excludes its boundary.

Now, the problems: Let $T$ be an equilateral triangle with sides of $1$ on a plane, $S = \{ A_1, ..., A_s \} \subset T$ be a set of some distinct points.

**The general problem:** Determine $$M_s = \max_{S \subset T} \left [ \min_{1 \le i < j \le s} d(A_i,A_j) \right ],$$ if it exists; otherwise, determine $$U_s = \sup_{S \subset T} \left [ \min_{1 \le i < j \le s} d(A_i,A_j) \right ].$$ Assume that:

$i) \; T \text{ is closed}, \; s = n^2+1 \; (n \ge 4)$.

$ii) \; T \text{ is closed}, \; s = n^2 \; (n \ge 4)$.

$iii) \; T \text{ is open}, \; s = n^2 \; (n \ge 3)$.

$(n \in \mathbb{Z^{+}})$

$\text{}$

This problem is posed by myself out of curiosity when I considered $ii, \; iii$ in the case of $n = 3$. I haven't solved even this particular case so far. Therefore, we can start with this case, which is  called **The specific problem** from now on. Also, FYI, the common situation (?) of the problems is originated from another problem which can be easily proved by the Pigeonhole Principle.

Thanks in advance!!!

**P.S:** I don't know exactly what to title and what to tag. So, if I had it wrong, please help me fix it, and thank you for that!

$\text{}$

**Update:** I don't know why but when I made up **The general problem**, I just totally forgot about the potential sub-problem of

$iv) \; T \text{ is open}, \; s = n^2+1 \; (n \ge 3)$.

Furthermore, I find it necessary to add some sub-results, which can be easily proved by the Pigeonhole Principle, as followed:

$a) \; \text{If } s = n^2+1$, $$U_s = \sup_{S \subset T} \left [ \min_{1 \le i < j \le s} d(A_i,A_j) \right ] \le \dfrac{1}{n}$$
$b) \; \text{If } s = n^2$, $$U_s = \sup_{S \subset T} \left [ \min_{1 \le i < j \le s} d(A_i,A_j) \right ] \le \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{n}$$

$(n \in \mathbb{Z^+}\backslash \{1,2\})$.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier i said value for $s= 3m+1$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}m}$, this is only true for $m=1$, for higher $m$ other orientation(i wish i can explain it by figures, but i am not familiar with figure plotting) of points exceeds this value. so my final answer is:

Value of expression is: $\dfrac{1}{\left [ \dfrac{s}{3} \right ]}$ if $s\neq 4$, and for $s = 4$ value is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, where $[x]$ denotes the maximum integer greater or equal to $x$.

Note that the answer remains the same for both open and closed triangles. If triangle is open one can take a triangle of length $1-\epsilon$ inside the original triangle with sides parallel, then find optimum orientation in smaller triangle and then make $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, to conclude expression of value remains the same.

Explanation: For $s= 4$, it turns out that optimum orientation is one in which three points lie on vertexes and one on orthocenter. For $s = 7$, optimum orientations consist of one with one point at orthocenter while other points at boundary, while other orientations with all points at boundary, but the answer is same $\frac{1}{3}$. For $s\neq 4$ and $s\neq 7$ and $s>2$, optimum orientation consists of points at boundary, with three points on vertexes.

Comment: Your results are really helpful in case $T$ is closed (as well as in case $T$ is open, if they're improved just a little). I just have two wonders as followed: $A.$ In case of $s = 3m$, why can't the result be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}m}$ (the optimum scenario is the same scenario of the case of $s = 3m+1$ excluding the orthocenter) ? $B.$ Can you prove your results?

Comment: About your second answer, I have some improvements and questions as followed (from now on, we just consider the cases of closed $T$ and $s \in \mathbb{Z^+} \backslash \{ 1,2,3 \}$): $C.$ In case of $s \in \{ 4,5,6,7 \}$, please provide a proof or a hint of one for your results. $D.$ In case of $s \ge 8$, your result can be improved to $\left ( \left \lceil \dfrac{s-1}{3} \right \rceil \right )^{-1}$. This is originated from your optimum scenario with the orthocenter added.